# Comparing a subset of a population with the entire population?

Tags: population, subset

Is it possible to compare and test actual subsets of a population to the entire actual population?

That is, let's say for a baseball team we want to know which players are contributing to the team's on-base percentage, which players are hurting it, and which players are performing at a rate indistinguishable from that of the team? We have the actual number of opportunities for the team and the actual number of times someone reached base, and then we have all the players and all of their opportunities and successes. Each player (and rate) is a subset of the team (and its overall rate).

Would one simply do a chi-square comparing each player with the team? Would one have to first subtract that player's numbers out from the team, to compare the player to the rest of the team? Or, as it would be simpler, could one compare each player to the team (including that player)?

Would there be a better way to run this sort of analysis, to answer the question of which subsets of a population are helping and which hurting the population performance?

Thank you for any assistance with this!